# REST API 2013 $skiptoken Doesn't work with $filter - returns the same result set

Tags: rest, paging

I'm trying to implement paging in SP 2013 REST. This is the endpoint / querystring that I have:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Projects')/Items?$top=15&$orderby=Created%20desc&$filter=(((Status%20eq%20%27Manager%20Review%27)))&$skiptoken=Paged=TRUE&p_ID=2761
```

Notice the "&$skiptoken=Paged=TRUE&p_ID=2761" - When I change the p_ID parameter - the results doesn't change. I understand that $skip doesn't work so I should do $skiptoken instead. But I've tried many times and the results stay the same.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I just saw this article: http://www.dev4side.com/en/blog/posts/2014/04/10/list-elements-pagination-with-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-%E2%80%93-part-1 - which basically says the only way to do paging is fwd? Please someone confirm if this is true. And if it is, please comment in this petition to fix it with Microsoft: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/suggestions/4606680-line-up-list-item-pagination-with-rest-api-using-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per OData V4 specification, SharePoint implements server-side paging and you can use the link provided in the "next" variable contained in the API results.

In case of XML/Atom response, you will find the next variable at XPath:

```
/feed/link/@href
```

or in case of JSON response, you will find the next variable:

```
{
    d: {
            results: [],
            __next: "https://ServerUrl/sites/SiteColl/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Testing%20List')/items?%24skiptoken=Paged%3dTRUE%26p_SortBehavior%3d1%26p_ID%3d1&%24top=1"
       }
}
```